# How to update the data in the DataTable with aid of a DataView?

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding

I have this part of code and when I add a row into a `DataView` the first row into the `DataTable` changes with the last row added after the first one.

```
DataRow drSeguro = this._dvSegurosVinculados.Table.NewRow();
drSeguro["RamoSeguro"] = Ramo;
drSeguro["Operacion"] = operacion;
drSeguro["Aseguradora"] = aseguradora;
aux = Convert.ToDecimal(this.bfSumaAsegurada.DataEntryText);
drSeguro["SumaAsegurada"] = suma; 
drSeguro["Propuesta"] = this.psHeader.IdSolicitud; 
this.BindingContext[this._dvSegurosVinculados].SuspendBinding();
this._dvSegurosVinculados.Table.Rows.Add(drSeguro);
this.BindingContext[this._dvSegurosVinculados].ResumeBinding();
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Well... when I add a new row into a DataView (_dvSegurosVinculados), the first one for example doesn't add a data value , but when I add more than one it does but the first row I added changes or replace its values with the last row added.